# HttpHandler doesn't render image on server

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have a `FileHandler.ashx` which implements `IHttpHandler`. The only thing this handler does is get the file and return it thru `context.Response`.

It works fine in my local unit even after publishing it (in my local machine). While on the server machine it only works if I run the website thru the Visual Studio, it doesn't work if I access the published website (i.e. http://url.to.site/).

This is what it looks like when running on my local machine (thru Visual Studio or published site), and thru Visual Studio on the server machine:
[image]

And this is what it looks like when accessing the published website on the server machine:[image]

This is a snippet from the `ProcessRequest` method of the `FileHandler`:

```
var strExtenstion = Path.GetExtension(file);
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", file.Length.ToString());

if (strExtenstion == ".pdf") { context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; }
else if (strExtenstion == ".png") { context.Response.ContentType = "image/png"; }
else if (strExtenstion == ".jpg") { context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; }
else if (strExtenstion == ".gif") { context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"; }
else if (strExtenstion == ".bmp") { context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"; }
else if (strExtenstion == ".txt") { context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; }
else {
     context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
     context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
}

context.Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
```

`file` is the path of the file.

** **UPDATE** **

If this would help: the server I used is a GoDaddy server which is maintained using Plesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer: I used the wrong variable in this line:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", file.Length.ToString());
```

`file.Length.ToString()` should've been `fileInfo.Length.ToString()`, but this code shouldn't have worked when run thru VS, strange.

Comment: This answer was long overdue. XD